# Building GCC with MPFR in the source tree is only handled for MPFR 3.1.0+

Tags: gcc, build

I've read the [installation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC), `./contrib/download_prerequisites` doesn't work for me because I am behind a proxy and unable to get wget working. So I took pointers from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gcc/wiki/index), downloaded GCC7.3.0 tarball from the mirror sites and decompress. Then I put the tarballs for MPFR,GMP,ISL and MPC to gcc7.3.0 *srcdir*, untar them and do the following for each of them:

```
mkdir gmp
mv gmp-* gmp
```

Then move out of this *srcdir* and cd to another *objdir* where I run configure.

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
configure: error: Building GCC with MPFR in the source tree is only handled for MPFR 3.1.0+.
```

The reddit wiki says `the gcc build process will automatically build gmp / mpfr / mpc / isl since you've placed them at the expected locations here.` I don't understand why the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two guesses: you either tried using an older version of MPFR (according to `contrib/download_prerequisites` for GCC 7.3 you need at least ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpfr-3.1.4.tar.bz2) or you've put it in wrong location (your snippet will put MPFR into `$SRC/gmp/gmp-X.Y.Z` whereas you need just `$SRC/gmp`).

Comment: versions are alright. Renaming `gmp-X.Y.Z` with `gmp` after decompressing worked.

Comment: that's exactly what reddit wiki asks to do as well, I got confused.